# Oracle SQL - Hour must be between 0 and 23 error

Tags: sql, oracle

I am running the whole query and everything runs fine, until at the end I get the error(title) and the output should be like the excel image below. I have tried keeping hours as char and num and date, however I am still getting the error. Any help would be appreciated. Please feel free to ask questions and check the code in your tool. Thanks

[image: Output_sample]

```
with ht as( 
  select labno, birthdt, spectype,
--to_char(
  ((dtrecv - dtcoll)
   + ( to_date(nvl(tmrecv, '0000'), 'hh24mi')
   - to_date(nvl(tmcoll, '0000'), 'hh24mi')) 
    ) * 24 
 --, 'hh24:mi' )
    as hours
  from azmsds.sample_demog_view 
  where tmrecv is not null and tmcoll is not null and dtrecv is not null and dtcoll is not null
),


  secondQuery AS (
    select
      ht.hours,    
      extract(year from ht.birthdt) as "YEAR", 
      extract (month from ht.birthdt) as "MONTH",
      count(distinct ht.labno) as "initialDbsReceiptCount<1",
     '~' AS EOL
    from ht   
    where 1=1
and ht.hours is not null    
      --and month not null
       AND ht.birthdt >= '01-JAN-12' 
    --   and hours <= 23 
       and ht.spectype in (1,5,7)
    --and hours > 23
    group by extract(year from ht.birthdt), extract (month from ht.birthdt), ht.hours
    order by extract(year from ht.birthdt) desc
  ),
  ThirdQuery AS (
    SELECT 
      sq.year,
      sq.month,
      sq."initialDbsReceiptCount<1",
      sq.eol
    FROM secondQuery sq
    WHERE 1=1
    --AND sq.hours <= 24
  )
select * from   ThirdQuery
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems to me you have some wrong data in iether tmrecv OR tmcoll...

if you do

```
select to_date('2500', 'hh24mi') from dual;
```

You will receive this error.

So I would start with trying the below selects to narrow down where the issue is

```
select to_date(nvl(tmrecv, '0000'), 'hh24mi') as hours
from azmsds.sample_demog_view 
where tmrecv is not null and tmcoll is not null and dtrecv is not null and dtcoll is not null
```

---

```
select to_date(nvl(tmcoll, '0000'), 'hh24mi')) as hours
    from azmsds.sample_demog_view 
    where tmrecv is not null and tmcoll is not null and dtrecv is not null and dtcoll is not null
```

One or the other of the above will give you the error, then you can examine the data from these fields to find the data that is causing you the error.

Answer (score 0):

It appears you have invalid time values. This should help identify the bad ones.

```
select * from azmsds.sample_demog_view
where
       tmrecv not like '[0-2][0-9][0-5][0-9]'
    or tmcoll not like '[0-2][0-9][0-5][0-9]'
    or not tmrecv between '0000' and '2359'
    or not tmcoll between '0000' and '2359'
```